# How to get multiple concurrent JQuery .load requests to run at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, concurrency

Does anyone know how to get the jQuery .load() function to work concurrently? Right now I have two .load() functions but jQuery only seems to run one at a time.

```
$('#div1').load(url);
$('#div2').load(url2);
```

I know most browsers can run 2 concurrent AJAX requests. Am I going to have to build a $.ajax() request for both of them? I'd rather not since the .load() is so much easier. :)

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE** 
These actually do run concurrently. I inspected FB and they both were running however the second wasn't returning anything so I "assumed" it wasn't working. After further inspection it wasn't returning anything because I was checking a session variable, which was being reset by the previous .load() request.

Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: When you say "concurrent", what do you mean? Most browsers still execute Javascript in a single-threaded state, so I'm curious. "Asynchronous" requests and a static drill "page load" are not synonymous.

Comment: That *should* load both at once.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I think the OP wants the browser to open two requests at once.

Comment: @alex - I'm not doubting you, but can you explain? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: In HTML5 you can user [web workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)

Comment: Your code should work as you expected. It should start two requests at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have does run both requests concurrently/without blocking. From the jQuery site:

`The async option to $.ajax() defaults to true, indicating that code execution can continue after the request is made.`

.load() is just a wrapper around the low level .ajax() and uses the defaults. Use the developer tools in your browser (i.e. Firebug in FireFox) to view the requests are both made and do not wait for the other to complete.

Comment: You are correct, they do run concurrently. I inspected FB and they both were running however the second wasn't returning anything so I "assumed" it wasn't working. After further inspection it wasn't returning anything because I was checking a session variable, which was not set yet because of the previous .load(). I will have to figure out a work-around for that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured out the problem!